# Math overflows tcolorbox - how to fix?

Tags: align, tcolorbox, overfull

I have the am making some notes, and I cannot figure out how to stop math blocks overflowing from a tcolorbox. Is there any way to fix this?:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\parindent 0in % controls indentation of paragraph start
\parskip 1em % controls the spacing between paragraphs
\linespread{1.5} % controls the line spacing

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{defn}{Definition}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}


% Meta information
\title{Algorithms}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \tcbset{before app=\parfillskip0pt}

    \maketitle
    
    \section{Asymptotic Analysis}
    \begin{defn}{$O(n)$ notation}{}
    % \begin{defn}[]{}
        $O(g(n)) = \left\{f(n): \text{there exist positive constants} \, c, n_0 \, \text{such that}:
        0 \leq c g(n) \right\} \text{for all} \, n \geq n_0$.
    \end{defn}
\end{document}
```

This is what it results in:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the problem by switching back to text mode for the text parts. This allows latex to add line breaks there:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\parindent 0in % controls indentation of paragraph start
\parskip 1em % controls the spacing between paragraphs
\linespread{1.5} % controls the line spacing

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{defn}{Definition}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}


% Meta information
\title{Algorithms}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \tcbset{before app=\parfillskip0pt}

    \maketitle
    
    \section{Asymptotic Analysis}
    \begin{defn}{$O(n)$ notation}{}
    % \begin{defn}[]{}
        \raggedright
        $O(g(n)) = \left\{f(n):\right.$ there exist positive constants $c, n_0$ such that: $\left.0 \leq c g(n) \right\}$ for all $n \geq n_0$.
    \end{defn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very helpful!

Comment: @quidproquo You're welcome!